# InDesign: single-line composer (paragraph style)

Tags: adobe-indesign, typography, creative-cloud

I've finally found out about the paragraph composer and how I can stop InDesign from meddling with my type automatically:
[image]

Is there a way to incorporate this into a paragraph style so that I don't have to keep setting it manually? Also what if I switch to 'single-line' but then another designer opens up the same file on their own machine?

Going by what I've read on Google, it seems like this isn't possible

Comment: The composer type can be chosen under _Justification_ in the paragraph style options, I believe.

Comment: So it can! Thank you!

Comment: I just upvoted you back to zero because someone claimed it was low effort and I can clearly see research.

Comment: @johnlewisdesign thank you! I think some of these downvoters need to take a long look in the mirror :)